# May a moderator be part of something she is moderating?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I am used to moderators always staying away of issues they are moderating. They may have something to say about it but never do so at the same article/thread/question/item they are moderating.

Is that so here? Is there any convention or rule about this in StackOverflow? May a moderator moderate her own contributions?

Example:

> Q by Mary: How to change unicorn color?
>   A by Ted: Use magical elixir because of this and that.
>   [Many comments with discussion about it]
>   [Comments moved by moderator Jane to chat, she leaves a comment with a link to chat and explains that comments are not for extended conversations]
>   Jane follows by posting this comment (not in the chat): Actually about those things there are details which date back to the nineties, you may whatch this video(link) about how they changed unicorn color with so few magical straw. But again, all this is associated with making your own stable. I think you should define up to where you want to learn really and then research more and more regarding this.

The answers make me realize that there are instances where it is acceptable for a moderator to moderate where she is involved. I'll add another example (the last one) with greater involvement by the moderator.
In total 18 comments. In this order (letter indicates author): SAFAFAFA(FAF)JJJAJJJ
J is the moderator. The three between parenthesis deleted, all others moved to chat by J briefly after last comment.

Comment: They usually don't, but what's wrong with doing it? I'm pretty sure they wouldn't abuse their abilities. See [who moderates the moderators?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/who-moderates-the-moderators?rq=1)

Comment: It means that they are not impartial since they are part of it. I've seen other sites where impartiality is not a requirement of moderation. And indeed it may be fine that way if there is no abuse of their abilities.

Comment: Moving comments to chat then commenting in that chat isn't really moderating yourself. Comments aren't meant for discussion and moving discussions to chat is just a part of how comments work (regular users can do it too after a certain number of comments have been posted)

Comment: There are plenty of other checks and balances, I'd say it's ok for moderators to act on posts they're otherwise involved in (asking, answering, voting, commenting, ...). If you have a specific issue to raise, please talk about that.

Comment: Related: [Should moderators be allowed to decline flags on their own comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224300/should-moderators-be-allowed-to-decline-flags-on-their-own-comments)

Answer (score 12):

The custom is that moderators refrain from acting as a moderator in cases where they have a conflict of interest. The most important case is probably using their own moderator powers on their own posts, e.g. reopening one of their questions. That is almost always a terrible idea and simply should not be done.

There are many lesser conflicts of interest a moderator might encounter. For example removing an answer on a question the moderator has answered as well. Strictly speaking, the moderator might benefit from this action because more votes might be cast for their answer instead of the now deleted, competing answer. But if the answer is e.g. blatant spam, there is really not much sense in the moderator waiting until a second moderator is available to remove it.

In my opinion, as important than the potential conflict of interest is how clear-cut the decision is. Removing direct and explicit insults towards another user is always justified, even if the target is the acting moderator. But any action that requires some judgement and is not a simple enforcement of unambiguous rules gets problematic very quickly once a moderator is involved in the issue and also acting as a moderator on it.

There is no hard rule on this given to the moderators by SE, but an abuse of the moderator position will lead to losing that position in the end. So moderators are advised to avoid acting in situations where this would mean the abuse of their powers, or just the appearance of abuse. But that does not necessarily mean they have to avoid *any* situation they were involved in a minor way, they just need to be able to defend any of their decisions.

Answer (score 4):

Most, if not all, of the site moderators were long time and active users of the site before becoming moderators.

Hence, each moderator has two hats: one is their moderator hat and the other is their "ordinary member" hat. And they're allowed to wear any of those in any given time.

What does it mean? If a moderator want to take part in comments, they have the full right to do that, and it doesn't have to come from them being a moderator, but as active members of the site. They can also post answers, and even ask questions. All is totally legit and acceptable.

Of course moderators are human and might cross some lines, but as Shog says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224304/152859):

> We do log everything, so if someone goes completely off the rails and decides to start abusing their privileges in a major way we can get a record of it

So if you really think a moderator abused their power, click the "contact us" link in the bottom, fill the form and explain why you think that.

Answer (score 4):

That's a *great* example of a moderator using her powers appropriately.

*Comments are not meant for discussion*. Comments are *also* a great tool for encouraging users to improve on their answers, and that's the right place and time for a comment.

If I were a regular user on that site. I would appreciate the restraint and proper use of moderator tools for greatest effect.

And moderators are *human exception handlers*. We deal with the things that need to be handled quickly, or of great importance trusted with keys to the metaphorical family car.

While some mods may refrain from moderating posts where they have an interest in, *completely* refraining from doing so, especially for a mod who is active on a site means we effectively lose a mod who can handle a chunk of flags. Its just not good policy. As such I try to be fair and evenhanded as opposed to completely neutral.

If we had a mod, who was abusing powers to do things like, say, deleting answers referencing rival products, or mass deleting certain classes of questions unilaterally, yeah, action needs to be taken.

Here? Not so much so.